# "cd" doesn't work in the first execution of the Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple batch that works well every time:

```
@echo off

set @TRUNK_DIR=%cd%

echo %@TRUNK_DIR%
```

I have the same lines as the first lines of a larger batch, but when I open a new prompt  the TRUNK_DIR variable is empty on first run batch and gives error. In this batch I put a new echo %@TRUNK_DIR% in the end of file and @TRUNK_DIR continue empty.

In the other plays batch works well.

What's happened? I don't have any idea.

Comment: `SET` only applies inside the current command prompt. Your sample works fine for me if I run `cmd` and call your batch file. If the behaviour only appears in one of the batch files, you're most likely doing something weird in it.

Answer (score 1):

This program should work, so my only recommendation would be to try running the file; only without the @ symbol.